# Set RollingUpgradePolicy for VMSS using Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure-powershell

I have a virtual machine scale set (VMSS) where I am trying to set the values on the RollingUpgradePolicy. I found [documentation here on PowerShell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmssrollingupgradepolicy?view=azps-9.6.0) for modifying it, but I can't quite get it to work. I'm attempting to use code like this:

```
$vmss = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "my-RG" -VMScaleSetName "my-scale-set";
Set-AzVmssRollingUpgradePolicy -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -MaxBatchInstancePercent 50 -MaxUnhealthyInstancePercent 50 -MaxUnhealthyUpgradedInstancePercent 50
```

After running this it seems like it's successful because it returns a JSON object and shows all the values set like I want, but when I go to confirm it by looking at the settings in the portal I can see that my VMSS hasn't changed. **Why is it not taking effect?** My hunch is that the `$vmss` variable I'm using is something like a copy of the VMSS and not a reference to my actual existing VMSS, but the documentation doesn't explain the $vmss variable or how to apply changes like I need. I'm also open to using CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After running this it seems like it's successful because it returns a JSON object and shows all the values set like I want, but when I go to confirm it by looking at the settings in the portal I can see that my VMSS hasn't changed

The `Set-AzVmssRollingUpgradePolicy` to modify the `RollingUpgradePolicy` settings in **VMSS** . The commands will return the `JSON` format with the updated settings, but it does not immediately affect in azure portal.

In order to update the upgrade  policy values, update the **VMSS** settings using the `Update-AzVmss` cmdlet after modifying the `RollingUpgradePolicy` settings. follow the the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/update-azvmss?view=azps-9.7.0) on updating the **VMSS** settings.

```
$VMS = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "v-venkat-mindtree" -VMScaleSetName "Venkatvmss"
Set-AzVmssRollingUpgradePolicy -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -MaxBatchInstancePercent 50 -MaxUnhealthyInstancePercent 50 -MaxUnhealthyUpgradedInstancePercent 50
Update-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "v-venkat-mindtree" -Name "Venkatvmss" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once ran the above commands **VMSS** upgrade policy was upgraded successfully.

[image]
Reference: [Set-AzVmssRollingUpgradePolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmssrollingupgradepolicy?view=azps-9.6.0)

Comment: Thanks VenkatV! Adding that last line of code did it for me.